# Hasnotice option while searching in app

Tags: bug, search, ios-app, post-notices

Searching for [not locked, not closed posts with notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasnotice%3A1%20closed%3A0%20locked%3A0) leads to different results in web and in iOS-app:

Web contains only 8 results and top voted post with 68 votes:

> [image: web]

App returns too many posts and first post with 2.7k votes:

> [image: app]

Looks like `hasnotice` option was ignored in app.

- App Version: 1.6.5.1
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: Same results in Android app, _long_ list, top votes is 2.7K.